# WebSphere Application Server 7 and WebSphere MQ 7, SELECTOR_NOT_SUPPORTED exception

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, websphere-7, jmstemplate

I have an application that take JMS messages from WMQ queue.  If the app is deployed on Tomcat then no problem.  But if the app is deployed on WAS7 then the following exception is raised:

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured
during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException:
JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'BOURSE_RECEIVE_QUEUE'. JMS attempted to perform an
MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error. Use the linked exception to determine the
cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined
correctly.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call
failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2318' ('MQRC_SELECTOR_NOT_SUPPORTED').
```

Also, if I do not use `correlationID` and receive message without the selector (which is set to `correlationID`), then no problem.  But I need this feature.

Any ideas?

Comment: What versions of WMQ client and server?  Can you post the code?  Selectors obviously work.  WMQ is even optimized to select on `correlationID`.  So the behavior you are seeing *must* originate in the code or config.  Although having the error message helps, posting the parts that are potentially at fault would greatly ease debugging.